# Convert and sent Grid to PDF

Tags: java, grid, pdfbox

I want to send my grid class as a PDF through mail but I guess I am missing something. Please provide me appropriate answer for that.

in my grid class i have 3 grids and i want to sent that grids as a PDF. How can I use pdfbox for that? Kindly suggest me examples.

java code

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();     
    doc.(new Output(globalParam);
```

pom xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: new Output(globalParam) it sis my Grid Class

Comment: You can edit your question. It makes no sense, what is a "grid class"? Or are you really asking "how to draw a grid"? And why are you using 2.0.17?

Comment: i am asking is i already have class. in that class i have a 3 grid now i want to sent that grids as a pdf

Comment: `i am asking is i already have class` - I have no idea what you mean. The second sentence seems to indicate you have an own class with a "3 grid". PDFBox doesn't know your code so you can't send your class. PDFBox doesn't support grid drawing anyway but there are libraries on top of PDFBox, e.g. EasyTable or Boxable.

Comment: Please don't Write with Random upper case Letters like This. It's very Annoying to read text Like that.